# Number of solutions of a trigonometric equation involving sine

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove that $$\sqrt {2}\sin (\sqrt {2}x)=\sin (-x) $$ has more than one solution (at $x=0$) ?

Comment: It has 8 solutions

Comment: @JanEerland, it has more than $8$ solutions. See answer below.

Comment: You posted this question and [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361938) within minutes of each other. I see no reason to make them separate questions, they're effectively the same question, but if you do make them separate the least you could do would be to link them to each other -- otherwise you're wasting everyone's time because people will work on one of them not knowing what progress has been made on the other.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number of values at which function attains maximum](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361938/number-of-values-at-which-function-attains-maximum)

Comment: @joriki I agree..but I'm not being able to delete the question as it has already  got answers...you may vote to close...sorry

Comment: @SanchayanDutta, how about you delete the other question and leave this one intact given this one has answers and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the question has not specified a range, then there are an infinite number of solution as can be seen in the graph below, where the blue curve is $\sqrt{2}\sin \sqrt{2}x$ and the red one is $\sin (-x)$:

[image]`

If you were to, however, restrict yourself to a specific interval, such as $[0, 2\pi]$ you would get the below graph:

[image]

From which you can clearly see that there are only four solutions.

Answer (score 1):

if the question is just,"has only one solution"? no,there infinite solitions[image]

as you can see from the graphic